# Facebook Delphi

Tags: delphi, facebook

Trying to post data to https://www.facebook.com/login.php using synapse delphi library but without any result. The post data was got from mozila headers viewer.
Answers?

Comment: My car is not working. Answers? Be more precise please.

Comment: This is your first question. So, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. But this cannot be answered. You need to give way more details. Code samples and full error codes/strings are often helpful. You can edit the question to add more details.

Comment: @Valera, welcome to stackoverflow.  Take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and please, edit your question to elaborate it.  Without any result is a very bad description for a technical problem.

Comment: *It always amazes me that people expect me to spend my time answering questions they won't spend their time asking.* (George)

Comment: @user194076 - I would say a dwarf crew stole a gas from your car. Try to check your current tankage :)

Comment: I recommend using ICS instead for your http calls: www.overbyte.be you get a lot more of control over what goes on and also it supports non-blocking calls.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know how to use [HTTP Post with Synapse](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=13013.0).  If you also need HTTPS support, you will need at least [release 36](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public%3ahowto%3asslplugin), and change some settings, such as port.  [Here is an example using TCP](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/public%3ahowto%3atcpwithssl).